# Svc Error for DLL i have not included

Tags: c#, dll

I am receiving an error for some unknown reason. I do not have Microsoft.Enterprise dlls in my project. I have tried adding them, but the issue persists.

http://pastebin.com/TxXFaQFB

Even when i do not have a reference to Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder it throws this error. I do not know why this suddenly has happened. It can't use a reference to a dll that i have not included. (????)

This issue was sudden. Some source have suggested that temporary files for .NET can cause the issue. Any clues?

Things i've tried.

1) Add the dll
2) Remove dll and any csproj reference.

Regards,

Daniel

Comment: try deleting the bin directory and rebuilding

Comment: I cleaned the solution. However, i will try physically deleting the bin file. What could be wrong here? So as to avoid it or recognize it in future?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @lockstock deleting the contents of the bin folder solved this issue and my svc projects build and ran perfectly.